# Error "package not available" when trying to install the "MAMI" package

Tags: r, package, cran, install.packages

I get this error when trying to install "MAMI" and "DataExplorer" packages.

> "Warning in install.packages :
> package ‘MAMI’ is not available for this version of R"

I have the newest version of R (4.0.3) and also tried deleting R and downloading an older version, which didn't work.

I am pretty much out of ideas regarding how to fix the problem. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the package "MAMI" is not on CRAN, but is located on R-forge.
To install it try the following:

```
install.packages("MAMI", repos=c("http://R-Forge.R-project.org", "http://cran.at.r-project.org"), dependencies=TRUE)
```

As described on the [MAMI R-forge page](https://mami.r-forge.r-project.org/)